# Data Structure: Dictionary Like Tree

Tags: data-structures

I think I've heard that there is data structure something like tree to store dictionary entries.

It may look like:

c ┬ a ┬ b
 
   │     ├ r
   │     ├ s ─ e
   │     └ t
   ├ i ─ ...
   ：

Is there any name for this data structure?

I cannot find it...

Thanks for your help, thank you in advance!

Comment: are you looking for Huffman coding?

Comment: @Dukeling Thank you so much! Prefix! Perfect!!!

Comment: @MotKohn It seems even better! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) might be what you're looking for.

> A trie, also called digital tree and sometimes radix tree or prefix tree ..., is a kind of search tree - an ordered tree data structure that is used to store a dynamic set or associative array where the keys are usually strings. ... [A node's] position in the tree defines the key with which it is associated. All the descendants of a node have a common prefix of the string associated with that node...
>
> [image]
>
> <sup>A trie for keys "A","to", "tea", "ted", "ten", "i", "in", and "inn".</sup>

Comment: How is it different with Hunffman coding that you mentioned on your comment?

Comment: Huffman coding is a way to compress one (or more) long strings (for storage), a trie is a way to efficiently store a bunch of strings that have common prefixes (for active usage). So if you have a dictionary (a bunch of unordered words where you just want to see if any given word exists or get a node, containing e.g. the definition, corresponding to a given word), a trie is perfect for that. If you have a long document (e.g. a book) that you want to efficiently store on your hard drive, Huffman coding would make more sense there.